# Pandas Dataframe Sample

Tags: python, pandas

Does anyone know how pandas.df.sample normalizes the weights: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

For example if I just give the weights counts for each input:
Does it just do something like [count1/sum_counts, count2/sum_counts, ...] ? Or does it do something such as Softmax? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the Pandas [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.0/pandas/core/generic.py#L4695-L4856) for DataFrame.sample, it appears that your first guess as to how weights are normalized ([count1/sum_counts, count2/sum_counts, ...]) was correct:

```
# Renormalize if don't sum to 1
if weights.sum() != 1:
    if weights.sum() != 0:
        weights = weights / weights.sum()
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid weights: weights sum to zero")
```